# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function updateUser()

Tags: php

This is My config code:

```
    require "functions/dbConnect.inc.php";
    require "functions/alerts.inc.php";
    require "functions/echohtml.inc.php";
    require "functions/SQLfunctions.inc.php";
    require "functions/validateLRForm.inc.php";
    require "functions/validateUpdateUser.inc.php";
```

This is my validateUpdateUser code:

```
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['confirm'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $realName = $_POST['realName'];
    $biography = $_POST['biography'];
    $profilePic = $_POST['profilePic'];
    updateUser($_SESSION['uid'], $username, $realName, $profilePic, $biography);
    header("Location: ../../social.php");
    exit;
   }
```

This is my SQLfunctions code:

```
function updateUser($uid, $username, $realName, $profilePic, $biography) {
        $dbConn = db_connect();
        
        // Construct the update query based on the provided values
        $updateSql = "UPDATE users SET";
        $updateFields = array();
    
        if (!empty($username)) {
            $updateFields[] = " user_name = '$username'";
        }
    
        if (!empty($realName)) {
            $updateFields[] = " user_realName = '$realName'";
        }
    
        if (!empty($profilePic)) {
            $updateFields[] = " user_profilePic = '$profilePic'";
        }
    
        if (!empty($biography)) {
            $updateFields[] = " user_biography = '$biography'";
        }
    
        // Check if any fields need to be updated
        if (!empty($updateFields)) {
            $updateSql .= implode(",", $updateFields);
            $updateSql .= " WHERE user_id = '$uid'";
    
            $updateResult = mysqli_query($dbConn, $updateSql);
    
            if ($updateResult) {
                // Handle the update success
                updateSuccess();    
            } else {
                // Handle the update error
                $error = mysqli_error($dbConn);
                mySQLerror($error);
            }
        }
    
        // Close the database connection
        mysqli_close($dbConn);
    }
```

I get the following error in Wampserver:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function updateUser()

I know it's something about the require/inludes, but I already checked and they are including the right files.

I tried changing the orders of required didn't work. Checked for typos, there were none.

Comment: Make sure all the `require` lines are at the beginning of `validateUpdateUser.php`

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.

Comment: I know my script is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, I'm just constructing the basic functions. I will worry about protection later. For now I want to understand why my current code is not working. Thanks for the input tho ;) .

Comment: "I'll worry about this later" Famous last words.